# How do I apply a custom ServiceStack RequestFilterAttribute to an auto-generated Service?

Tags: servicestack

I have a custom RequestFilterAttribute that I am applying to my ServiceStack services:

```
[MyCustomAttribute]
public class MyService : ServiceStack.Service {...
```

I have recently begun using the AutoQuery feature (which is awesome) but I'm wondering how to apply MyCustomAttribute to the auto-generated services that you "get for free" when your request DTO inherits from QueryBase.

I could certainly add methods to my service with the "magic" AutoQuery code:

```
SqlExpression<DTO> sqlExpression = AutoQuery.CreateQuery(request, Request.GetRequestParams());

QueryResponse<DTO> response = AutoQuery.Execute(request, sqlExpression);
```

but I'm hoping there's a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to customize the AutoQuery behavior you should first take a look at the [extensibility options using Query Filters](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-Query#extensibility-with-queryfilters) provides.

Otherwise you should be able to add the RequestFilter Attribute to the Request DTO itself, i.e:

```
[MyCustomAttribute]
public class MyQuery : QueryBase<Poco> {}
```

Alternatively you can get a reference to the auto-generated Service using:

```
var autoQueryService = appHost.Metadata.GetServiceTypeByRequest(typeof(MyQuery));
```

And then use the dynamic API to add custom attributes to it, e.g:

```
autoQueryService
    .AddAttributes(new MyCustomAttribute { ... });
```

Since the Services are only generated and registered once the `AutoQueryFeature` Plugin is executed you'll only be able to access the service after all plugins are loaded which you can do:

1) [In your own plugin](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Plugins#plugin-api) by implementing the `IPostInitPlugin` Interface

2) By registering a `AfterInitCallbacks` handler:

```
this.AfterInitCallbacks.Add(appHost => { ... });
```

3) By overriding `OnAfterInit()` virtual method in your AppHost, e.g:

```
public override void OnAfterInit()
{
    ...
    base.OnAfterInit();
}
```